# From Xml point of view, what is action, category and data(of intent filter of Android) called as?

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

We have terms like attributes, name , elements etc.

[image]

In XML point of view, What is "action", "category", "data" and "intent-filter" called? What the name given for those?

Answer (score 0):

THat means whenever an application sends an Intent with action=VIEW and a url that starts with geo://, that the Activity with this filter can be started to handle it.  Usually you would put a URL as well so it would only handle geo://url, but they decided not to here.  The usual usecase for this is deep linking.